# How can I get my grails app to log in a way that shows up in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk 'logs' tab

Tags: grails, logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

According to http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/index.html?using-features.loggingS3.title.html only log entries logged into Tomcat logs via java.util.logging will be made accessible.  Grails uses Log4J.  How would I best bridge the two?  I do not want to have to ssh into the instance every time I want to look at a log message.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Log4J JUL bridge.

See: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64008 for discussion

The bridge: http://people.apache.org/~psmith/logging.apache.org/sandbox/jul-log4j-bridge

The relevant config (in .properties format) seems to be:

```
log4j.appender.jul=org.apache.log4j.jul.JULAppender
log4j.appender.jul.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jul.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, jul
```

Try around with various Config.groovy translated versions of that and see if that gets you anywhere.